# How to add flags and/or arguments to a command in the 'sudoers' file

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, users

How would I add flags and/or arguments to allow users in the sudoers file to run certain parts of commands, such as only allowing a user to run `sudo rm` and not `sudo rm -rf`? I am using 14.04.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset,pwfeedback
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
Ruby    ALL=/usr/bin/apt-get update,/usr/bin/rm,/usr/bin/rmdir,/usr/bin/mkdir

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: I do not think you can have that fine grain of control over the commands directly. You can make a script, owned by root, in /usr/local/bin and give sudo to that. your_command -your_options @ , just test the input.

Comment: Say you block `rm -rf`. What's to prevent `rm -f / -r`?

Comment: Please explain the problem you have and not the solution you believe you need to apply.  What you want here is not possible and the reason for it is because this method would be full of holes (as @muru already posted).

Comment: I do not have a problem I am just very curious.

Comment: Good answer :P @Rinz see response`

Comment: @alex ah good to know. What works is a "whitelist" -but- the fact you let that person use `sudo` is the problem: for instance a `cp` can be an used as an equivalent to `rm` making your `rm` fix in the sudoers file useless. If this would have been related to for instance updating /var/www/ for apache there are better methods (that is one example people need access outside their home).

Comment: So then how would I whitelist commands like that? I have been working with ubuntu and linux in general for about 3 years now and I have never worked with permission type stuff before.

Comment: I think there are ways to exert the control you desire, but even if you control the rm command, what would stop someone from running mv / /dev/null  anyhow,  it would appear you want a pseudo sudoer.   perhaps someone who can modify system files, or access certain hardware, but not someone who can destroy the system easily.  Perhaps it would be easier to control which shell a user logs into.  There prolly like a million answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there isn't a way to control sudoers in the way requested, although there are fine grained permissions available in the system:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

But even that isn't quite enough, you'd basically have to replace all the standard program libraries with scripts to filter flags. Which would be messy and potentially break the system.

Instead consider flipping the problem and creating users who don't need sudoers. Making sure they're in the right groups and using ACLs to expand permissions where needed so they can access the files they need without causing issues.